# Error says "camera is undefined", but I did define it

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

My camera function is not working.  The error says that `myCamera` is undefined, but I ***did*** define it.

According to the error message, `Camera` is an unknown override specifier.

Here I have included the camera header so this should be fine.

**level.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "Vectors.h"
#include "level.h"



#include "glut.h"
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include "controls.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SOIL.h"
#include <vector>
#include "camera.h"
class Scene{

public:
    level(Input *in);

    void renderer();

    void handleInput(float dt);

    void update(float dt);

    void resize(int w, int h);

protected:

    void displayText(float x, float y, float r, float g, float b, char* string);

    void renderTextOutput();
    void calculateFPS();



    Input* input;


    int width, height;
    float fov, nearPlane, farPlane;


    int frame = 0, time, timebase = 0;
    camera myCamera;
};
```

**level.cpp:** yet here it claims myCamera is undefined.

```
level::level(Input *in)
{
    // Store pointer for input class
    input = in;

    //OpenGL settings
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                            
    glClearColor(0.39f, 0.58f, 93.0f, 1.0f);            
    glClearDepth(1.0f);                                     glClearStencil(0);                                  
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                            
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                             
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);  
    glLightModelf(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, 1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);




    gluPerspective(55.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 1, 50.0f);


    camera.position.x = 0;
```

Here is the camera class; however there are no error messages, so if anything is wrong here I don't know what.

Comment: you need to give us a bigger part of the `scene.cpp` and `scene.h`

Comment: *scene.h here i have included the camera header so this should be fine* -- It won't be fine if that header is included in two or more C++ compilation units.  You have a global variable that will be declared multiple times when the linker gets a hold of your modules, causing a linker error.

Comment: please include a [mcve]. The code you post should be enough to reproduce the error but not more (you dont have to post the trigonometric calculations if thats not relevant for the problem)

Comment: It appears that `scene.cpp` does not have a `#include "scene.h"`.  Hard to be sure because `scene.cpp` is a excerpt instead of being a [mcve].

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the only other time I included camera.h is in camera.cpp

Comment: In Scene.ccp you use `myCamera` in the middle of nothing, so it obviously do not exists. You should use it inside a method of  `Scene` e.g. in the constructor if you want to initialize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a cyclic include dependency. `scene.h` includes `camera.h` and `camera.h` includes `scene.h`.

So when you try to compile `camera.cpp`, the preprocessor first includes `camera.h`. In there it sees the include of `scene.h`. In `scene.h` it sees the include of `camera.h` again, but the `#pragma once` will prevent it from being included again. Note that at that point, `camera.h` has only been read up until `#include "scene.h"`. Therefore, when the compiler gets to `camera myCamera`, the type `camera` is undefined because the corresponding header file is not yet read completely.

To resolve this, remove the include of `scene.h` in `camera.h`. You don't use it there anyway. If you need types from there, consider a [forward declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c).

Also, having this:

```
#pragma once
...
#ifndef _SCENE_H
#define _SCENE_H
```

does not make sense. The `#pragma once` fulfills the same task as the include guard `_SCENE_H`. Use one of them, not both.